# MongoDB keeps querying namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my rails app I'm using mongoid and in the logs before pretty much every query, even on the same request, it also does

```
MONGODB dbname['system.namespaces'].find({})
```

What is this doing? Is this a performance concern? Can I somehow cache so it doesn't have to do this all the time or at least stop it from clogging up the logs?

Edit: Here's the relevant portion of the log

```
Processing by FilesController#new as HTML
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Sep 09 15:59:43 -0700 2011
[Barista] Compiling all scripts for barista
[Barista] Compiling all coffeescripts
[Barista] Copying all javascripts
MONGODB db['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB db['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e6a949935d3e9726b000001')})
MONGODB db['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB db['files'].find({:token=>"nonssb38"})
```

Comment: There is no reason during normal operation to query the namespaces collection. Are these queries coming from mongoid?

Comment: I'm not doing any mongo myself so it must be mongoid

Comment: Can you post the full query you are running and the log of that whole query? Perhaps this will make more sense when its placed in context.

Comment: Edited to include the log with full query info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in Mongoid until 3.0 comes up. Notice that this only happens in development mode, so it's not much of a big deal.

References:

- https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1465
- https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1291

Answer (score 1):

Well its performing an operation on the database so I don't see how its clutter when you have your normal queries in the logs as well. The [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Metadata) for MongoDB states that the `<dbname>.system.*` namespaces keep database related metadata in them.

You most likely cant cache it since its data that may need to be updated on each query as part of some database housekeeping. I'm looking in the source for some concrete answers.

Comment: There is no reason for mongo to query the namespace collection for every query, and in fact it does not. This might be mongoid automagically trying to do something in which case that magic is either badly implemented or the OP is doing something wrong.

Comment: @Devin, Remon, Could you elaborate on what this information is that it queries and why does it need this. I couldn't dig up much information about it.